# Sign In - following upgrade from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2.3.1, magento-upgrade

If you Sign In to your account and then Sign Out again whilst on the Home page or Category Page you get the following error :-
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactoryInterface in /var/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116 Stack trace: #0

If you Sign In when on a product page the error occurs straight away.

This started after updating from v2.3.0 to v2.3.1

Initially on updating I had to disable several Magento modules that were causing the following error when running the command to Re-index

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\StockIndexTableNameResolverInterface in /var/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116 Stack trace: #0

I solved the reindex issue by disabling a number of modules in config.php

I am assuming my current Sign In issue is similar but I'm not sure what to disable.

I have tried the usual commands to Update and Compile with no result.

Does anyone know what modules could be related to the error - Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactoryInterface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you have Redis installed? If so, open a CLI window and enter:-

`redis-cli`

followed by:-

`FLUSHALL`

this will clear any information in the Redis cache. Now we need to enable all of the Magento modules with the following command:-

`bin/magento module:enable --all`

That should fix it :)

Comment: this solved the issue. There must be some inconsistencies/conflicts with the modules I had enabled/disabled in 2.3.0 which were caused by the upgrade to v2.3.1 enabling some new elements.

Comment: Enabling everything has removed the issue and I will slowly work my way through disabling anything I don't need

Comment: For reference I ran the following commands after clearing the VAR, Generated/Code and Pub/Static/frontend directories

redis-cli, FLUSHALL, bin/magento module:enable –all, bin/magento setup:upgrade, bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB -f, bin/magento setup:di:compile. 

It might be more than was necessary but it did the job

Answer (score 0):

Just run search in code. If you use PHPstorm ctrl +shift + f on magento directory.

If you don't use any IDE you can run this command in console

```
grep -rnw 'yourmagento/app/code' -e 'CarrierFactoryInterface'
```

Check also your theme:

```
grep -rnw 'yourmagento/app/design/frontend/' -e 'CarrierFactoryInterface'
```

This will help you track what module or theme customisation is causing your issue.

Comment: Magento_shipping and Magento_quote came up. Disabling Magento_quote caused other issues and Magento_shipping was already disabled

Answer (score 0):

For reference I ran the following commands after clearing the VAR, Generated/Code and Pub/Static/frontend directories

- redis-cli
- FLUSHALL
- bin/magento module:enable –all
- bin/magento setup:upgrade
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB -f
- bin/magento setup:di:compile

It might be more than was necessary but it did the job